# No socket created by Gunicorn causes nginx to throw 502 error

Tags: nginx, django, gunicorn

Following [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04?comment=47694), I was able to set up Django, Gunicorn & nginx **inside a virtualenv** on an AWS EC2 instance (running Ubuntu 16.04), and then proceed to create an Upstart file to "daemonize" the entire thing.

After activating the virtualenv, I checked that:

1. **Django works** - I was able to access my Django project via port 8000 by running the following:

`./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

When visiting `mydomain.com:8000` I was welcomed by the default Django page.

2. **Gunicorn works & is able to serve the Django app** - I was able to access my Django app by running this from my project's folder (replace `projectname` with my actual project name):

`gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 projectname.wsgi:application`

When visiting `mydomain.com:8000` this time I was greeted again by the welcome page, and when appending `/admin` to the end of the URL I was able to see the login screen *minus* the CSS (because Gunicorn isn't aware of the static CSS files, which is OK for now according to the tutorial).

From here I proceeded to create the following systemd file (when `masterfolder` is used to show the folder in which all the action takes place, `myuser` is my system user (`ubuntu`, as this is an Ubuntu instance) :

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=myuser
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/myuser/masterfolder
ExecStart=/home/myuser/masterfolder/myvirtualenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/myuser/masterfolder/projectname.sock$

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target`
```

I encountered two problems:

1. **No socket is being created** - when checking the nginx log files **outside as well as inside** the virtualenv (not entirely sure why they are the same, btw) I saw the same error:

`2017/01/17 15:12:43 [crit] 12403#12403: *3 connect() to unix:/home/myuser/masterfolder/projectname.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream`

Now, note that `masterfolder` is consistent with the folder hierarchy `django-admin` creates when I run a `startproject`:

`masterfolder/
├── manage.py
└── projectname
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── settings.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── wsgi.py`

When looking inside `masterfolder` there is indeed **no .sock file at all**, never mind one that is named `projectname.sock`.

2. **Therefore, despite the fact that nginx works, it throws a 502** -

This is how my `etc/nginx/sites-availabe/projectname` file looks like:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.mydomain.com mydomain.com MYIPADDRESS;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/masterfolder/projectname;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/myuser/mastefolder/projectname.sock;
    }
}
```

It's symlinked correctly, of course, and after every change I make to try and fix it I run:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl start gunicorn
sudo systemctl enable gunicorn
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

I feel as if I'm missing something basic here in the understanding of how all of this infrastructure works together. Feel free to point out errors in my understanding of the process, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked permissions of the `masterfolder` directory?

The permissions should be `myuser:www-data`.

Also there is a spelling mistake in your nginx config file. Hope that's a typo:)